# LG G2 has horizontal stripes on the screen when displaying high resolution images with moire pattern

Tags: screen

Recently my LG G2 sometime has horizontal stripes on the screen. Firstly I thought that these stripes appear randomly and the problem might be related to connection between the screen and other hardware. But today I realize that the appearance is not random. When I open a specific type of image, that is images with moire pattern, these stripes will appear. These stripes will disappear when I open an image without moire and appear again when I open another moire image.

The phenomenon reduces when I zoom in the image. Also, the stripes won't appear if I resize the image to smaller resolutions.

The stripes appear whether the image is displayed in the galaxy app, or the default web browser, or chrome browser. Even when I set the image as the wallpaper, the stripes appear right on the wallpaper.

I have delete the system cache but it doesn't help.

In the picture below, stripes appear when I opened a image of grasses which has moire pattern.

[image]

[image]

Have you ever encounter similar problems? And can you guess this problem is caused by the hardware or software?

Comment: Are you talking about the white lines where the flowers are, just before the big gray/white part of the image ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев: Thank you for your reply. I have posted another image which illustrate the problem. These lines have random color and keep blinking.

Comment: Ugh.. that doesn't look too good. You say it only appears on images with these colors and nothing else ? What happens if you zoom the image, does the stripes change/change position/move at all ?

Comment: Try one of these https://www.reddit.com/r/lgg2/comments/3efz9y/lg_g2_secret_codes/ and look for the screen diagnostics. See if you can make anything out of it. Are you runing stock android, have you rooted/instaled anything fromwtihing recovery/ etc ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев: I still use the stock android. The secret code works and I can access the hidden mode of the phone. But the solution in that link doesn't help. Thank you very much for your help ^.^

Comment: @ИвоНедев: I have notice that it's not the color causes the problem but the moire pattern in the image. I have test with multiple images which contain moire patterns and the randomly moving horizontal lines appear with almost all of of these images.

Comment: I'm going to guess It's a software issue.  Try viewing same photo with the stock Galleries, and google Photos to see if there's a difference at all. Also if you set for instance the second image from your question as a wallpaper, how's the lines then ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев: the lines still appear whether the moire images are displayed in the stock galary, stock web browser, or chrome browser. 

I also set the image that I showed above as the wallpaper and now the lines appear right on the wallpaper. However, the problem is less severe since the image is displayed in full screen (the appearance of lines always decreases when I zoom in the image). Also, for the same image, if I resize the image to smaller resolution, says 320x180, the lines will not appear.

Comment: Is this stock android, or have you installed something custom ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев: it's stock android.